# Can Solr use field values of a known document in a query?

Tags: solr, solr4

I would like to perform a Solr search using the values of certain fields of an indexed document which I can identify by its id.  With MLT this is somehow possible, but I would prefer a regular query parser.  Can I somehow use subqueries to inject the result of a subquery into the main query?

For example, let's say I have indexed information about books into solr, where each document represents a book, with an id, title and author field.  At query time I have only the document id availible and I would like to search for books by the same author in a single step.  Is this possible without using MLT?

Comment: Can I ask what do you mean by "At query time I have only the document id availible"? Have a you looked at the faceting mechanism on solr? What you can do here is to introduce id, title and author field as different facets and then you can simply query for a documents with certain values in a specific field(s) or query for document within a specific ranges if your data is numeric.

Comment: @sam Facets are great, but won't help in my case as long as I do not have the desired facet value.  Basically, I have the unique identifier of a Solr document, but I do not have any other data. I could execute a Solr query to retrieve the contents of the desired field (who is the author of book with id=x), and in a second step use the result to search for documents with this value (books by the author).  Instead I am trying to do this in only one search, something like "find all documents of type book that have the same author as book with id=x"

Comment: you dont need to have the desired facet value. For instance let's say we have two books from authors "John Smith" and "John Grisham" when you create a query you can specify that you are looking for all the documents that have an author john and the result from solr will contain books from both authors. Isn't that what you're trying to do? Please correct me if I didn't understand what you are trying to do correctly. I am not clear in why you think you need to have the exact value of the field. Even if that is the case facets will still solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JOIN](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join).

```
http://HOST:PORT/CORE/select?q={!join from=author to=author}id:<ID>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I saw the JOIN discussion on the Solr tracker before posting my question, but did not realise it could be used this way.